# How to return only particular fields to list using LINQ lambda expressions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve an object from entityframework without ONE field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973529/retrieve-an-object-from-entityframework-without-one-field)

I am working on asp.net mvc. currently i am using EF 4.1 code first model. Here i have list of records(43). My class is like,

```
public class MyTable
{
public string field1{get; set;}
public string field2{get; set;}
.
.
.
public string field20{get; set;}
}
```

and i am returning them as a list like List. But i dont want the field20 to return. so how could i skip particular field in my list. I have used like,

```
(from m in context.MyTable select new{m.field1,m.field2,...,m.field19}).ToList();
```

Its working very fine. but i want same result using lambda expression syntax like

```
context.MyTable.Skip() or any etc.
```

How to return only particular fields to list.

Comment: So was my comment helpful? Have you found another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

well you can write

```
context.MyTable.Select(x => new { x.field1, x.field2, ..., x.field19}).ToList();
```

If you don't want to write all 19 fields, you can make you `MyTable` class implement `IEnumerable`

```
public class MyTable : IEnumerable<object>

public IEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator()
{
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    list.Add(field1);
    list.Add(field2);
    ...
    list.Add(field20);
    return list.GetEnumerator();
}

System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

And then you can write

```
context.MyTable.Select(x => x.Take(19).ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i know the method you answered i need to write 19 properties is there any way to skip single column.

Comment: I think it's possible only by two ways - through reflection and if your MyTable will implement IEnumerable. I've changed an answer, may be it will help.

Comment: This solution is very useful when one of the fields in the database is a byte[ ], skipping this when iterating through this table is much, much faster.