# How to Except Property instead of Select in Lambda LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a code that fetching a table. Here's my sample code:

```
public IQueryable<MyItem> MyItems(){
    return context.MyItem;
}
```

Here are the sample properties of MyItem

```
public int Id {get;set;}
public byte[] Image {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
```

Since, `byte[]` can have multiple characters, I don't want to include then in searching because it will take so long if I have a records like 10,000 items.

Typically, I would `Select` like this:

```
public IQueryable<MyItem> MyItems(){
    return context.MyItem.Select(item=>new MyItem{
        Id=item.Id,
        Name=item.Name
    });
}
```

This is okay for few properties, but what I have a 10-20 properties, it would be hassle to write them one by one.

Is there any way like, I just Except the property `Image` in lambda for shorter code?

Comment: Seems like you need to split your table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973529/retrieve-an-object-from-entityframework-without-one-field
Possible help: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/table-splitting-in-entity-framework-6-code-first-approach/

Comment: Which EF version is this? Both EF core and "classic" support table splitting, but the implementation is slightly different.

Comment: @jsonGPPD I posted an answer. Do you have any issue with this or that's not what you want?

Answer (score 6):

Create your own extension method `SelectExcept`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> SelectExcept<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> sequence,
    Expression<Func<T, TKey>> excluder)
{
    List<string> excludedProperties = new List<string>();
    if (excluder.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression)
    {
        excludedProperties.Add(memberExpression.Member.Name);
    }
    else if (excluder.Body is NewExpression anonymousExpression)
    {
        excludedProperties.AddRange(anonymousExpression.Members.Select(m => m.Name));
    }
    var includedProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Where(p => !excludedProperties.Contains(p.Name));

    return sequence.Select(x => Selector(x, includedProperties));
}

private static T Selector<T>(T obj, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties)
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    foreach (var property in properties)
        property.SetValue(instance, property.GetValue(obj), null);

    return instance;
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = context.MyItem.SelectExcept(x => x.Image);
```

You can exclude more than one property:

```
var result = context.MyItem.SelectExcept(x => new { x.Image, x.Name });
```

Comment: using System.Reflection; might helpfull

Comment: This method gives an error. Error is "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method".

Answer (score 4):

You can use [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper) for this. Just create a DTO class with all the properties excluding those which you don't want to query:

```
public class MyItemDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then add some mapping:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
{
    cfg.CreateMap<MyItem, MyItemDTO>();
});
```

Now you can query your entities like this:

```
context.MyItem
    .OrderBy(m => m.Name)
    .ProjectTo<MyItemDTO>();
```

This extension is available in `AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions`.

You can also create a DTO class with all the properties from an entity and then ignore some of them in mapping:

```
cfg.CreateMap<MyItem, MyItemDTO>().ForMember(d => d.Image, m => m.Ignore());
```

If you use **EF Core** you can instantiate entity class inside LINQ query so it's possible to map entity to itself and ignore some properties from it without creating additional DTO classes:

```
cfg.CreateMap<MyItem, MyItem>().ForMember(d => d.Image, m => m.Ignore());
```

Then you just use `ProjectTo` with the entity type which excludes unwanted properties from SQL query:

```
context.MyItem
    .OrderBy(m => m.Name)
    .ProjectTo<MyItem>();
```

Note that you may also need to create mappings for each navigation property of an entity.