# Load properties of a type without other properties of a type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, automapper, eager-loading

Is it possible to eager load one property of a type without loading all it's properties?

**Real life situation:**

I have two entities, MediaLink and MediaItem.

My media item looks like this:

```
public partial class MediaItem
{
    public MediaItem()
    {
        this.MediaLink = new HashSet<MediaLink>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MediaLink> MediaLink { get; set; }
}
```

When writing a query, I need to access the `MimeType` of the `MediaItem` from the `MediaLink` entity.

Yet when I use the navigation property to access the MimeType, the query also returns the `Content` which on a video could be >10MB and cripples the performance.

I suspect this is not possible, but is there any way I can return the MimeType property of a MediaItem without it's content via EF?

EDIT: Thanks for the comments, I should probably add that I think I could do this with a standard linq query by projecting the parent `MediaLink` and the property I want from `MediaItem` into a new type but I'm needing to do this inside and AutoMapper mapping.

At the moment, the below mapping requires me to go into the `MediaItem` via the navigation property:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MediaLink, MediaModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MediaTypeId))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.MimeType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MediaItem.MimeType));
```

What I really want to do is something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MediaLink, MediaModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MediaTypeId))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.MimeType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (from mi in src.MediaItem select mi.MimeType)));
```

And hope the projection would return the whole `MediaItem` entity.

Comment: don't think so, you need to define separate entity, that holds *only* information you care about.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274241/entity-framework-4-selective-lazy-loading-properties

Comment: What does `MediaLink` look like? Couldn't you just store the MimeType along with the link for quick reference?

Comment: That's weird, co-developer called James in the office just suggested that! Yeah I think I'm going to end up going down that route, either that or create a new 'MediaContent' type which just contains the content and hangs from 'MediaItem'