# Entity Framework Database First only use certain columns

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

We are currently working on a application which uses entity framework 6, database first approach.  There are a few tables we need to pull in, joining them, but they have many columns which we do not want to pull in.  I can delete the columns in the edmx but then they regenerate whenever we update the edmx, is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324064/how-to-get-some-columns-of-entity-in-entity-framework

Comment: Another link you might find helpful in your situation is table splitting as explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj715645.aspx and also in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVxvrjoIPRk

Answer (score 2):

Well, let it pull all the columns. Still you can select only few columns or the columns you need while displaying or passing as model using a LINQ query `Select()` method and project to a anonymous type.

Other than that, DB First model UI also gives you facility to import `Views` and `stored procedure`. That means, whichever customized data you want you can pull the required SQL to a `create view ...` statement or `create procedure...` statement and have it imported using Entity Framework.

Comment: I agree. Either create a static typed model to project onto, or project onto an anonymous type using the `Select` method