# EF Core. How to load only necessary properties from deep nested entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I develop a simple application, something like a chat where every message may contain text and files.
Entities are related like this:

Message group -> every message group has a collection of messages -> every message has a property 'FileCollection' -> 'File collection' has 4 collections: Images, Video, Audio, Files. All of them has the same relations in database. To show this logic here is my query to get all message groups with their entities:

```cs
var messageGroups = await _db.MessageGroups
    .Where(mg => mg.UserId == id)
    .Include(m => m.Messages).ThenInclude(mes => mes.FileCollection.Images)
    .Include(m => m.Messages).ThenInclude(mes => mes.FileCollection.Video)
    .Include(m => m.Messages).ThenInclude(mes => mes.FileCollection.Audio)
    .Include(m => m.Messages).ThenInclude(mes => mes.FileCollection.Files)
    .ToListAsync();
```

The problem is that every type of file (Image, Audio etc.) has a 'Data' column in Db (property in EF Core) which contains their blob data. I want to exclude all blob from query, because query becomes extremely heavy loading all user files from Db. Something like this (but exclude method does not exist):

```
.Include(m => m.Messages).ThenInclude(mes => mes.FileCollection.Video).exclude(video => video.Data);
```

Is there any way to use explicit loading at the end of the query? Or maybe there are attributes like [JsonIgnore] which excludes class property from Json serializing? Or any other method?

If it helps: ImageFile, AudioFile and others inherit from File super class:

```
public class File
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("content_type")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    [Column("file_name")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [Column("length")]
    public long Length { get; set; }

    [Column("related_file_collection_id")]
    public int FileCollectionId { get; set; }

    public FileCollection FileCollection { get; set; }
}


public class ImageFile : File
{
    [Column("data")]
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

}
```

I need all properties from 'File' class without 'Data' property from it's child classes.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate question. This post provides two methods (split table and projection) for handling this situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274241/entity-framework-4-selective-lazy-loading-properties

Comment: It's a good idea to send 'Data' column to it's own table. It can be the answer, thank you. But I believe it's not the most elegant way. Or EF Core is not so powerful to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please include the class definition for FileCollection as well as any Fluent API model configurations for FileCollection.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way would be to configure your DbContext for those entities containing Blob columns using [Table Splitting.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting)

Don't let the name confuse you. This technique is not to move the Blob to a different table. Instead, it will allow you to fit two "entities" on the same row.
In your case, you could split your `File` from your `FileData`, meaning that you will have a different entity for each of them, but both will be stored on the same row on the same table.

By using table splitting, you can `.Include` your `File` and it won't include the `FileData` unless you explicitly tell EF Core to do it.

If you don't wanna go down that road, I believe that you would either need to write some custom Selects or custom SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[NotMapped]` attribute but then you will not be able to retrive that column from the db from other queries.

You can also create a DTO and select only the required properties, but that would not be elegant considering all your includes.

Comment: I know, but I need that column in Db. It are user files, they send them in messages and they need it. With [NotMaped] there won't be such column in Db and files will be not saved.

Comment: The solution is not to insist on EF too much. Use queries !

Answer (score 0):

As it was advised here, Table splitting can be the answer, but it is a little complicated. I've just modified my query using .Select(). Not very elegant, also I have a cycle inside cycle, but it works:

```
List<MessageGroup> messageGroups = await _db.MessageGroups.Where(mg => mg.UserId == id).AsNoTracking().AsSplitQuery().Include(m => m.Messages).ThenInclude(mes => mes.FileCollection.Images)
                                                                                                                             .Include(m => m.Messages).ThenInclude(mes => mes.UrlPreviews).ToListAsync();
foreach (var mg in messageGroups)
{
    foreach (var m in mg.Messages)
    {
         m.FileCollection.Video = await _db.Video.Where(video => video.FileCollectionId == m.FileCollection.Id).Select(v => new VideoFile(v.ContentType, v.FileName, v.Length, v.FileCollectionId, null)).ToListAsync();
         m.FileCollection.Audio = await _db.Audio.Where(audio => audio.FileCollectionId == m.FileCollection.Id).Select(a => new AudioFile(a.ContentType, a.FileName, a.Length, a.FileCollectionId, null)).ToListAsync();
         m.FileCollection.Files = await _db.Files.Where(file => file.FileCollectionId == m.FileCollection.Id).Select(f => new OtherFile(f.ContentType, f.FileName, f.Length, f.FileCollectionId, null)).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

null in file constructors is where byte[] blob data should be.

Comment: I used this approach and the key is the AsSplitQuery(). This will make EF Core use a separate query for the child objects. You can then update the query for the child objects to include only the wanted properties before it is executed. I didn't get the performance improvement without AsSplitQuery

Answer (score 0):

One other solution is to (re-)construct your entity using `Select`.

```cs
_dbContext.MyEntity.Select(
    myEntity => new MyEntity()
    {
        Property1 = myEntity.Property1,
        Property2 = myEntity.Property2
        // do not select / load Property3
    });
```

EF Core will translate this query in such a way that in the `SELECT` SQL-statement it only accesses the fields used in your query. This way, the other large columns are not loaded from the database.

However, this solution only works if you have a suitable class constructor or you can set properties to empty or dummy values, and is therefore not generally applicable.